# A formal word for someone who is being or has been persuaded

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm interested in finding a word for a person who is being or has been persuaded.

The person doing the persuasion is called a "persuader", but the person being persuaded is called a "persuadee"? I'm wondering if there is a more formal or more well-known alternative word choice.

*Depending on where a persuader is coming from, a(n) X will react very differently*

Comment: The persuader and the persuaded?

Comment: I'm thinking "persuaded" suggests that the persuasion worked. I'd like a word that emphasizes that this person is a receiver of persuasion while still remaining agnostic about whether they have changed their beliefs.

Comment: Convert?  . . . . .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! When using a tag please click to read its explanation. In the case of [single-word-requests] we have the following, 
*This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.*   I hope this helps!

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica thanks for showing me this, I just added a sample sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target audience, focus....also found the snippet below:

https://law.marquette.edu/facultyblog/2015/06/persuading-people-who-dont-want-to-be-persuaded/

PERSUADING PEOPLE WHO DON’T WANT TO BE PERSUADED

> “It’s not me; it’s you.” This tidbit all lawyers know: no matter how
> great and logical your argument, “if it doesn’t resonate for the
> **recipient**, you won’t get anywhere” (173). So, when persuading, we need
> to hook our **recipients** so the argument will resonate with them. How?
> Stories.

Answer (score 1):

*From SOED*

> **-ee** from verbs, with the sense 'person subject to an action or involved in an action', as *employee, payee, devotee, escapee, conferee, standee*

The nouns collected in the entry are found in the dictionary but this suffix is rather freely productive so that you can say **persuadee**, which is not found in the dictionary I use.

Answer (score 1):

How about *convert* or *proselyte*. Would that work?